# exception in Java swing application action listener

Tags: java, swing, exception, action, listener

I am doing exception in my action listener, I'm new in all this so I need help.

I tried many ways, now I am going with this:

```
JButton buttonIzracunaj = new JButton("Izra\u010Dunaj");
    buttonIzracunaj.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0)
        {
            int danInt = Integer.parseInt(textFieldDan.getText());
            int mjesecInt = Integer.parseInt(textFieldMjesec.getText());
            int godinaInt = Integer.parseInt(textFieldGodina.getText());

            if(danInt <= 31 && danInt > 0 && mjesecInt > 0 && mjesecInt <= 12 && godinaInt > 0)
            {
                int dan = danInt;
                int mjesec = mjesecInt;
                int godina = godinaInt;
            }

            String poruka = null;
            if ((danInt<1) && (danInt > 31))
            {
                try {
                    throw PremaliBrojException;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    poruka = "Unijeli ste pogrešnu vrijednost.";
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, poruka);
                }
             }
             int proteiniInt = Integer.parseInt(textFieldProteini.getText());
             int ugljikohidratiInt = Integer.parseInt(textFieldUgljikohidrati.getText());
             int mastiInt = Integer.parseInt(textFieldMasti.getText());
             int godineInt = Integer.parseInt(textFieldGodine.getText());
             int masaInt = Integer.parseInt(textFieldMasa.getText());
             int aktivnostInt = Integer.parseInt(textFieldDuljinaAktivnosti.getText());
             int hrInt = Integer.parseInt(textFieldProsjecniHR.getText());

             if(isMTrue)
             {
                 if (godineInt > 0 && masaInt > 30 && aktivnostInt > 0 && hrInt > 0)
                 {
                     double brojKalorija = (double) (ugljikohidratiInt * 4 + proteiniInt * 4 + mastiInt * 4) - (((-55.0969 + (0.6309 * hrInt) + (0.1988 * masaInt) + (0.2017 * godineInt)) / 4.184) * aktivnostInt);

                     round(brojKalorija, 3, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
                     poruka = "U suficitu ste ~ " + brojKalorija + " kalorija.";
                 } else {
                     poruka = "Unijeli ste pogrešnu vrijednost.";
                 }
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, poruka);
             }
         }
     });
     panelIzracun.add(buttonIzracunaj);
```

nothing happens, it calculates everything right but I need to have excepion. Should I put it outside of action listener? or even outside the initialize()?

```
public class PremaliBrojException extends RuntimeException{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public PremaliBrojException(String message) {
    super(message);
}
```

}

Comment: Post the stack trace (the exception) for us.

Comment: public class PremaliBrojException extends RuntimeException{
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

 public PremaliBrojException(String message) {
  super(message);
 }


 
 
 
}

Comment: Not the class, the actual output in the console that you're receiving.

Comment: I am getting:
U suficitu ste *some number* kalorija. (from poruka = "U suficitu ste ~ " + brojKalorija + " kalorija.";)
like exception isn't there

Comment: even if I write 50 for a danInt

Comment: the logic is wrong, should be `<1 || >31`

Comment: dear God I feel stupid now xD thanks, I thought problem was way way more complicated :)

Answer (score 0):

Handle exception in actionPerformed or set default exception handler with Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler.